# How to submit form data through VSCODE?

Tags: php, html, node.js, forms

I'm having trouble submitting form data through VSCODE. So basically I have a nodejs program that runs on vscode and my goal is to submit some input data from that to a online form for example.

1. Run the program.js file in vscode
2. The file picks out a username field
3. Submits it to a online file through php

This is the HTML file & PHP file that writes input username data to data.txt

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<BODY>
<form action = "submit.php" method="POST">
    <p>
        <input type = "text"  name = "username" />
    </p>
    <input type = "submit" name="submit_btn" id = "submit" value = "Submit"/>
    </form>
</BODY>
</html>
```

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
 {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $text = $username ."\n";
  $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a+');

    if(fwrite($fp, $text))  {
        echo 'saved';

    }
fclose ($fp);    
}
$lines = file("data.txt"); // Get the file as an array
$lines = array_unique($lines); // Merge all duplicate lines
// Save as a new file
$file = fopen("datacurated.txt", "w");
fwrite($file, implode("", $lines));
fclose($file);
?>
```

So the html file is not really important but I'm not so good at coding I was trying to send a post data request through vscode but didn't work.
I was wondering if it's possible to get rid of the html file and keep the php online and have it write the needed data. I need the delete duplicate text function in the php file as well.
Is this possible using AXIOS in vscode?

Comment: How/where does Node come in?

Comment: The node program runs fine I want to make a separate node.js file that would write username data to the php and submit it

Comment: and get rid of the html if possible

Comment: I think you need to add clarifications to your original question. 1. Where is program.js? 2. Picks out a username field from where? 3. What/where is the "online file"? What do you mean by "submit through php"?

Comment: Do you have the url for that "online form"?

Comment: at the moment i'm running tests on localhost so basically i need a way to submit data to a online php www.website.com/submit.php. Through vscode using nodejs if that makes sense... The online form is the html part i provided above only 1 input field

Comment: what is `program.js`? Why do you need an editor to send a POST request? Where is your PHP running?

Comment: program.js is a nft art generator.. I want to generate a user id and post that through the php. The php will be hosted on my website later on... sorry i left a lot of data out but i need help sending the post request through node.js only

Comment: Note that the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

As the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package has been deprecated, install [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) instead.

Then your Node code:

```
(async () => {
  const { body } = await got.post("https://www.website.com/submit.php", {
    json: {
      username: "Whatever..."
    }
  });
  console.log(body);
})();
```

You don't care what [www.website.com/submit.php](http://www.website.com/submit.php) is written in, but you have to be certain that that server will accept a Http Post request from your computer. It is trivial for them to obstruct what you are trying to do by filtering out your domain or by adding a Captcha.